# Update entity with one to many relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3.

I have a entity with 7 one to many entity and one to many. Majority of them have a cascade all

I create a rest api where some fields  and a list (who represent a one to many relation), it's a dto.

I was thinking to get the entity via a findById and update the fields and the list related to the dto.

Do i need to fech all one to many relation otherwise when i will save all item of these relations will be removed?